# how to change the format of datetime column when it is bound dynamically in gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt,dt1;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            dt = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
            e.Row.Cells[4].Text = dt.Month.ToString() + "/" + dt.Day.ToString() + "/" + dt.Year.ToString();
            dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[5].Text);
            e.Row.Cells[5].Text = dt1.Month.ToString() + "/" + dt1.Day.ToString() + "/" + dt1.Year.ToString();
        }

    }
```

This is my code and the column with index 5 is a datetime the problem is that it can be NULL so the following error turns up when it is

**"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"**

Any Solution Please help??!

thank u!

Answer (score 2):

Try using [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) instead and only if it returns true run the rest of the code

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt,dt1;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            bool success = DateTime.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[4].Text, dt);

            if(success)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].Text = dt.Month.ToString() + "/" + dt.Day.ToString() + "/" + dt.Year.ToString();
                dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[5].Text);
                e.Row.Cells[5].Text = dt1.Month.ToString() + "/" + dt1.Day.ToString() + "/" + dt1.Year.ToString();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also according to MSDN documentation calling Convert.ToDateTime(null) will return DateTime.Min so I'm not sure how you are getting a null exception

Comment: Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.TryParse(string, out System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\InventoryLastec\SearchResult.aspx.cs 29 28 C:\...\InventoryLastec\
it shows this error

Comment: it says &nbsp; cannot be converted to datetime wen my datetime column is null

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a simple check?

something like

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[4].Text))
    e.Row.Cells[4].Text = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[4].Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
else
    e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "-";
```

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the BoundField.DataFormatString and the BoundField.NullDisplayText properties, like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="BoundFieldExample" runat="server">
     <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataFormatString="{0:d}" NullDisplayText="Not Found" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The above will display dates in short date string format for the current culture and the text "Not Found" for Null values.
See GridView [BoundField Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6f329ah.aspx) for more information.